# FGETCSV documentation flaw

Tags: php, fgetcsv

I've been trying to figure what the `length` parameter in `fgetcsv` mean? THe documentation states that it is:

> Must be greater than the longest line (in characters) to be found in
>   the CSV file (allowing for trailing
>   line-end characters). It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this
>   parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.0.4 and later) the maximum line
>   length is not limited, which is slightly slower.

That made no effort to explain the specific purpose of the `length` resource. It just gives information on requirements.

Can someone please tell me what this does. Google was no help. I think its the key to allowing me to read only the first row of my csv file but I'm not sure. I tried testing it with a value of `1` but it returned a full array of rows still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the limit of length of every line you read, if you set length to 1000, mean you could only read 1000 byte data for each line.

Comment: Ah so its just a limiter for how much per row it can process. Thanks.